# Jira XRAY - Failing to import an xml using xray

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I am trying to upload xml to jira using xray api.

```
for %f in (D:\xray_test_junit\*) do curl -H "Content-Type:text/xml" -X POST -H "Authorization:Bearer %token%" --data @"%f" http://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v1/import/execution/junit?testExecKey=MYPROJECT-1234
```

Getting below error:

`{"error":"Project Key and Summary are required to create a new Test"}`

Note -
summary = test case name(not exceeding chars in failed xml) and Key = MYPROJECT-1234

if we split one xml file into multiple (one xml file = one testcase), only one or two xml are not able to upload out of 400 testcases. if we remove starting character (eg. src to rc) or one of character from testcase name(from xml file) xml get uploaded successful but other 399 testcases getting upload with same starting word and number of characters greater than failed testcase xml.

sample result.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite tests="2" skips="0" name="pytest" failures="0" errors="0">
<testcase name="src/sampletests//test_descover_user.py/test_get_user_name" time="0.012245601474" line="211" file="tests/test_descover_user.py" classname="tests.test_descover_user.TestGetUsers">
<properties>
<property name="tags" value="AUTOMATED_UT"/>
</properties>
</testcase>
<testcase name="src/sampletests//test_descover_user.py/test_get_user_id" time="0.012245701774" line="211" file="tests/test_descover_user.py" classname="tests.test_descover_user.TestGetUsers">
<properties>
<property name="tags" value="AUTOMATED_UT"/>
</properties>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
```

anyone can please help me ?

Comment: 1. Can you please share your junit xml report having all the results? Do you want to update an existing test execution instead of creating a new one each time you upload the results, correct? Otherwise you could specify the projectKey parameter

Comment: @Sérgio I have updated  junit xml report having all the results. yes i wanted to update result with existing instead of creating new test case each time on different Test Plan

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the problem in my head so I can help out but it's not yet totally clear to me.  Can you give an exact junit xml content and its request that leads to the problem and also the error message you get? So I can try to replicate it in a single command? Btw, can you also please identify the pytest and python versions?

Comment: I've imported the junit xml sample you provided, multiple times, to an existing empty Test Execution, without problems. Two tests were provisioned during the first import and then they were reused. Once again, if you can isolate the problem, by defining an exact request that can replicate the problem, it would be helpful and maybe then we can figure out what's wrong.